# Packaging built binaries with setuptools

Tags: python, pip, setuptools, distutils

I need to provide a `foobar.so` file in my pip package. `foobar.so` is built during the package installation, but not in a traditional way (ie. not gcc + .c file). Let's say I use a commande `./build_foobar` to build it. I guess [distutils Extension](https://docs.python.org/2/extending/building.html) is not what I need here. Then I need to ship it in the virtualenv `bin` directory.

What is the minimal `setup.py` configuration to do that?

Comment: so `foobar.so` is a separate program with a `main` function that should be installed along with the python package to be later callable via `$ foobar`?

Comment: In my very case, foobar.so is a uwsgi plugin. The pip package depends on uwgsi.